# Cordova Audio Streaming Delay in Android

Tags: android, html, cordova, streaming, cordova-media-plugin

When I try to call audio with html5 or cordova media plugin, there is a delay approximately 40seconds. But it works in pc browser.

I send my code below.

```
var my_media = new Media("http://85.111.25.40:8000/stream/1/;", onSuccess, onError, status);    
my_media.play();
```

OR

```
<audio controls autoplay>
                <source src="http://85.111.25.40:8000/stream/1/;" type="audio/mp4"></source>
            </audio>
```

config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a delay because cordova-plugin-media download the full file and after this its starts playing.

I was able to perform the streaming of mp3 file, the trick is use mu3 file instead of a mp3 file.

So I get my mp3 file e create a mu3 file like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:924, Example artist - Example title
http://s3.amazonaws.com/path/my_audio_file.mp3
```

I saved the below code as file.mu3 and upload it to my S3 bucket.

The *924* number after #EXTINF: represents the time of the audio (my_audio_file.mp3) in seconds.

More about M3U: [Click Here](https://www.lifewire.com/m3u-file-2621955)

And I use the link of the file.mu3 instead the mp3 file on cordova-plugin-media. **And plays right away, no delay at all.**

I'm using Ionic2 with the plugin arielfaur/ionic-audio to manage audio files, and this plugin uses the cordova-plugin-media to play native audio. I have the same problem and post that same solution here: [Github Issue Link](https://github.com/arielfaur/ionic-audio/issues/95#issuecomment-282276726) 
and worked for another person.

Best regards

Comment: Cesar thanks for your answer. But this is not a solution for Android.

Comment: If you use cordova-plugin-media give a try.

Comment: Can you share your mu3 file for me test here?